# How to solve nestjs public api cors error

Tags: cors, nestjs

im writing RestFull Api with NestJS. I want everyone to access this API, but I'm getting a cors error. Previously, I could do this by giving "*" to the origin parameter, but after the last Google Chrome update, Chrome does not allow this anymore. How did you fix this problem?

[image: This is how I solved the cors problem before. But right now, I want to allow all domains, not a specific domain.]

[image]

Comment: Why not just remove `enableCors`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?, it should be enable cors and accept all client url.

```js
app.enableCors({ origin: true });
```